# Blessed are the undefiled in the way

Tags: verbs, adjectives

The word blessed describes what?  The undefiled in the way or just the word undefiled?  Is the word undefiled used as noun?  Why is it in past tense?

Comment: This is from the bible, KJV psalm 119.  Make sure you tell us the source of any quote.

Comment: _The undefiled_ is an adjective being used as a noun, meaning 'undefiled people' (people who have not been defiled, or made impure). This was common in older English - 'the poor', 'the wounded' and so on - but is less favoured in contemporary English.

Answer (score 2):

The full sentence, from the Bible Psalm 119 is

> Blessed are the undefiled in the way, who walk in the law of the LORD.

Blessed describes the "undefiled in the way". These are also described as the people who "walk in the law of the LORD", so people who walk in the law of the LORD are blessed.

Undefiled in the way is not a common idiom.  Probably it has a particular meaning in Hebrew.  I suppose it means "people who follow Jewish religion purely"

It's not past tense, it is past participle used like an adjective. The syntax is poetic.

> Eaten is the apple on the table.

> Blessed are the meek.

Your sentenence has a subject

"The undefiled in the way, who walk in the law of the LORD"

A verb

"are"

and an adjective as the complement

"blessed"

Comment: So what do you call that undefiled in the way, should it be called phrasal noun?

Comment: It is a noun followed and modifed by a preposition phrase.  Like "The cat on the mat"

Answer (score 0):

#### It's an archaic translation.

The King James Version of the Bible was translated hundreds of years ago, and it's written in an archaic dialect of English that is no longer used. It's basically written in an entirely different language. An English learner should not be using it as a reference, just like how they shouldn't use the works of Shakespeare as a reference for learning English.

If you want to study the Bible, as an English learner, I would recommend a more modern translation such as the [New International Version (NIV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_International_Version), the [New American Standard Bible (NASB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_American_Standard_Bible) or [The Message](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Message_(Bible)) as suitable translations of the Bible.

A more modern translation of that verse from the New International Version of the Bible is as follows:

> Blessed are those whose ways are blameless, who walk according to the law of the Lord

Psalm 119:1

Comment: I am trying to identify the noun and verb and adjective in the passage.  If you would be asked by your student and you are not prepared to answer because you do not study this, then you would fail.

Comment: @windjar The King James Version of the Bible is sufficiently archaic that it is essentially written in a different language to modern English. Studying it is not useful for students of modern English. Would you like me to write an explanation of the modern translation of that sentence?